# SQL Server 2008 import wizard

Tags: sql-server-2008

CSV File contains 3 Lacks (329 columns), I am trying load using import wizard. But it's not importing the data, it's raising an "unexpected  and unrecoverable" error

And I changed the transaction log for db property also, it's not working pls suggest me.

Comment: First of all: please post the **complete and actual** error message you're getting - and secondly: do the 329 columns match the columns in the table you're trying to insert into? What are you mentioning the transaction log for?? What did you "change" there exactly....

Comment: Thanks for reply. this is the error "unexpected and unrecoverable",automatically termenating and i increate the database  properity for Files option database log files option.. increated  700 mb...